# willChangePlotRangeTo: makes no difference to graphs in Core Plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

i have the below code running in my app to stop the y-axis from being zoomed and scaled during touch or pinch gestures. I have axisConstraints assigned already, as are the globalXRange and Y.

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CGPoint)displacement{
return CGPointMake(displacement.x,0);
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
 willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
         forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate{
if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY)
{
    newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
}
NSLog(@"Plot changes %@", newRange);
return newRange;
}
```

My issue is that from the logs, 4-5 plot changes are recorded in the log while the page is first displaying when first running the app?? The code seems to work correctly, just i get no plots, plus no label + ticks on the Y.

```
2013-11-10 17:30:52.259 MyApp[8953:a0b] Pinch changes <<CPTPlotRange: 0x8d96680> {0, 30158.4}>
2013-11-10 17:30:52.260 MyApp[8953:a0b] Pinch changes <<CPTPlotRange: 0x8d94e70> {0, 40}>
2013-11-10 17:30:52.260 MyApp[8953:a0b] Pinch changes <<CPTPlotRange: 0x8d94330> {0, 34.44}>
2013-11-10 17:30:52.268 MyApp[8953:a0b] Pinch changes <<CPTPlotRange: 0x8da6da0> {0, 30158}>
2013-11-10 17:30:52.268 MyApp[8953:a0b] Pinch changes <<CPTPlotRange: 0x8da80e0> {0, 9}>
```

EDIT:

I did some mucking around with inserting NSLOG and the below code is what is creating the a gesture:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace2 = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph2.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace2.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace2.delegate = self;
plotSpace2.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger([difference integerValue]*1.03)];
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(9)];
plotSpace2.globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger([difference integerValue]*1.03)];
plotSpace2.globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(9)];
```

so having plotspace.delegate=self was the cause, changed to x.delegate=self and that fixes the gesture issue i was seeing.

Unfortunately the code i have for zooming only the x makes no difference. :-/

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: Running 1.4 Core Plot and Xcode 5.0

Comment: EDIT: specifically the plotspace.xRange & yRange lines

Comment: Eric: i tried some code you posted here in Mar last year, but doesn't work i guess due to newer version??  question:9495423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegate is preventing any changes to the `yRange`. Set the plot space delegate *after* you set up the initial `yRange`.

```
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                 length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(9)];
plotSpace2.delegate = self;
```

This behavior changed in release 1.4. In prior releases, `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` was only called when pinch-scaling. Now, it is called any time the plot range changes.

Comment: is there a way to identify the 2 plotspaces i have and programmatically change both given the touch gesture on either?

Comment: If you're using the built-in user interaction, it will update both plot spaces automatically. The plot space being changed is the first parameter to the delegate methods. If you are changing the plot spaces some other way, you can use the `-[CPTGraph allPlotSpaces]` method to get an array of all of the plot spaces in the graph.